# Call function when PyQt QWebEngineView is finished rendering

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

[`QWebEngineView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html) and [`QWebEnginePage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html) have `loadFinished`, however, per [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#loadFinished), "This signal is independent of script execution or page rendering." I want to call [`QWidget.render()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#render) (`QWebEngineView` implements `QWidget`) when the website is finished RENDERING... [the only solution i've seen to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57957098/9044183) is to just give up and use [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) to just wait 1000ms, which is a very bad solution in my opinion. If it takes less than 1000ms to render, time is wasted just waiting. If it takes more than 1000ms, then it's not finished rendering and even bigger problems emerge. I need to know *exactly* when `QWebEnginePage` completes its rendering so I can save it as an image as fast as possible.

Comment: There is no such exact point when the page has finished rendering, since it may load any number of different resources and there is no way to know in advance how long the entire process will take to complete.

Comment: I don't need to know in advance, i'd just like a function call when the page is safe to save as an image

well past me would need that, i've implemented a selenium based alternative solution for my needs.